# How to better structure mongoose schemas with relationships

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

At the moment i have 4 models. User, profile, interests and tokens. Between user and profile there is a one to one relationship. Between User and tokens there is a one to many relationship. Between profile and interests there is also a one to many relationships, interests will be pre defined with the ability for an admin to add more later.

User

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    phone: [{countrycode: String}, {number: String}],

    tokens: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Token'}],

    profile: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'
    },
},
{
    timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
});
```

Profile

```
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({

        username: {

            type: String,
            unique: true,
        },

        firstname: {

            type: String
        },

        lastname: {

            type: String
        },

        gender: {

            type: String
        },

        dob: {

            type: Date
        },

        country: {

            type: String
        },

        city: {

            type: String
        },

        avatar: {
            type: String
        },

        about: {
            type: String
        },

        interests: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Interest'

        }],

    },
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    });
```

Token

```
var TokenSchema = new Schema({

        name: {
            type: String,
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    });
```

Interests

```
var InterestSchema = new Schema({

        name: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    });
```

Have i set up these schemeas/relationships properly? Now if i wanted to give roles to a user would i create a new role schema?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Relational database if you want to make relation in NoSQL db

Comment: Im learning how to use NoSQL db, so tell me how should it be structured if i needed to store those data?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add relations in NoSQL. Only thing you can is to use schema as type of field in another schema, like

```
var Comments = new Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  date: Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
  author: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  body: String,
  date: Date,
  comments: [Comments],
  meta: {
    votes : Number,
    favs  : Number
  }
});

mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost);
```

[Embedded Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html)

Comment: How would u relate a comment to the blog post? in that way

Comment: Theres no relations. This is grant only that in BlogPosts you will have an array of Comments  with structure of Comment schema. When you request some BlogPost you will get Comments in comments field. But you can't add one object Comment into two different BlogPosts. This will be two different objects. BlogPost1.comments[0]._id not equal BlogPost2.comments[0]._id. This is NoSQL, so no relations. If you need relations - this is not your DB.